# How to arrange 4 social media icons in a row

Tags: html, css, web

I'm totally new into HTML and CSS and I want to arrange four icons in a horizontal row, now it's vertical…

```
/Users/ws-017/Desktop/Bildschirmfoto 2015-08-28 um 14.17.07.png
```

HTML Code:

```html
<img src="img/artwrk.png" alt="ARTWRK" height="250" width="250">
    <header style="text-align:center"> 
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/iamartwrk/" target="new" title="Soundcloud"> 
            <img class="socialicon" src="img/soundcloud.png" height="50" width="50"> 
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/iamartwrk/"target="new" title="Facebook"> 
            <img class="socialicon" src="img/facebook.png" height="50" width="50"> 
        </a> 
        <a href="https://twitter.com/iamartwrk/" target="new" title="Twitter"> 
            <img class="socialicon" src="img/twitter.png" height="50" width="50">
        </a> 
        <a href="https://instagram.com/iamartwrk/" target="new" title="Instagram"> 
            <img class="socialicon" src="img/instagram.png" height="50" width="50"> 
        </a>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this css `header a{display:inline-block; width:60px;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/ygay1scd/

Comment: now they're arranged as a block and not in a row, and they have a black frame haha

Comment: I just deleted some other CSS and now it works haha, can you tell me how to set the same distance between all the icons?

Comment: Give them a width e.g 40px

Comment: can i ask one more question? :)

Comment: What is it.  Depends ;)

Comment: I now have my main logo and the 4 social media icons together as i want them, but they're on top of the page, i want them to be in the vertical center, how do i do that?

Comment: you want the header to be in the center?

Comment: yes, but then it's not a header anymore haha, right?

Comment: create a div and position it absolute at top:50%;

Comment: div {
    top: 50%;
}

Comment: like this? i don't know

Comment: you're better off using vh vertical height http://jsfiddle.net/vjmj2ab8/1/ use relative actually

Comment: somehow this doesn't work for me, now the logo is at the top and the icons are at the bottom

Comment: post your css for gods sake

Comment: did you try it with absolute

Comment: don't know how this site works but i hope it does

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=6hyia2KcDC

Comment: and if i change the div to "inline-block" than the logo goes to the right side

Answer (score 0):

you can use this: a{float:left; width:20px}

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a table or would consider to use a table to output. Here in my own case, when I was designing an email template for the company I'm working with, this is how I align the Social Media icon with this code:

```
<table width="20" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" style="color: #ffffff;">
            <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="25" height="25" style="display: inline-block;" border="0" />
            </a>
        </td>                                       
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" style="color: #ffffff;">
            <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="25" height="25" style="display: inline-block;" border="0" />
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" style="color: #ffffff;">
            <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn" width="25" height="25" style="display: inline-block;" border="0" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps?